# android update recyclerview list without refreshing screen

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver

I have little experience with android background service and using broadcast receiver.
my app has a list of orders, with accept and decline button..
clicking on both buttons, api is called, which will only update the recyclerview list for the user who clicked it.

what i want to achieve is, when user clicks on button, with api call, recyclerview list should update for all users if there screen is open, without refreshing.
how to achieve this scenario? please help.

Comment: Keeping efficiency aside ... create a handler which calls API every 5 seconds so that whenever there is change it will reflect in other user end also

Comment: Thanks @PraveenSP i thought of that solution, but like you said its not the efficient way. as well not the correct way.

Comment: Since you already tagged with Firebase and Android, I'd recommend starting with the [Firebase codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). This teaches you how to build a chat app, which is pretty close to what you're describing: when one user posts a message, that shows up for all users who have the app open.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Unlike this chat example , we do not use firebase database. database is on server..so m still stuck with the same issue